# How to use OOP in Kivy Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Please help me, my competition is around the corner 
I tried to use OOP in Kivy. This is my simple Python code for testing:

```
class location:

    def __init__(self, total_house, total_land):
        self.total_house = total_house
        self.total_land = total_land


class test(BoxLayout):

    def addNum(self):
        App.get_running_app().x.total_house += 1

class testApp(App):
    x = location(NumericProperty(10),NumericProperty(5))


testApp().run()
```

this is my kv file:

```
<test>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: str(app.x.total_house)
    Button:
        text: 'add'
        on_press: root.addNum()
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF8iA.png)

I want the output to be 10 and when the button is pressed the number is added by one.

Please help me, I am new to KIVY

Comment: Have you tried replacing `x = location(NumericProperty(10),NumericProperty(5))` with `x = location(10, 5)`?

Comment: what is `numberx` ?

Comment: @RufusVS sorry that actually x.total_house

Comment: @Weebify if I replace it with location (10,5) I can't added them by 1. it will show 10 and 5 even I pressed the button. (Sorry my English is bad)

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting pure value from Kivy Property is to use the built-in `.get(EventDispatcher obj)` method from the `kivy.properties.Property` class:

```python
class test(BoxLayout):
    def addNum(self):
        App.get_running_app().x.get(EventDispatcher()) += 1
```

But before that, you need to import the `EventDispatcher` class first:

```
from kivy._event import EventDispatcher
```

Also please note that while this works in theory and it will indeed change the value of the *x variable*, I would recommend directly changing the *label's own text*, something like this:

.py

```python
def numberify(*args):
    # This functions is for universally changing str to either int or float
    # so that it doesn't happen to return something like 8.0 which isn't that great
    a = []
    for w in range(0, len(args)):
        try:
            a.append(int(args[w]))
        except ValueError:
            a.append(float(args[w]))
    return a if len(a) > 1 else a[0]

class test(BoxLayout):
    def addNum(self):
        self.ids.label1.text = str(numberify(self.ids.label1.text) + 1)
```

.kv

```python
<test>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: str(app.x.total_house)
    Button:
        id: button1
        text: 'add'
        on_press: root.addNum()
```

Learn more about Kivy Property [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html) and understand how it's not always necessary to use them :)